# Which passive component is best for 4 input one output?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, analog, passive-components

In our project we use 4 different CAN transceivers, 4 different CAN transceivers has 4 different INH pins.

Either of one CAN transceiver wakes up and enables the INH PIN which awakes the PMIC and supplies the whole system.

Circuit:
[image]

There are 4 INH inputs from 4 different CAN transceivers and one out put to power management IC.

I need a components which takes 4 inputs and gives 1 output.

I planned to go for OR gate but there is no supply for OR gate VCC in the system unless INH wake up the power management IC.

Is there a passive component which can take 4 inputs and one output.

Is there a diode with 4 input and single output?

Kindly suggest me

Comment: What's wrong with 4 diodes to OR four inputs?

Comment: What kind of transceivers are you using?

Comment: because OR gate has VCC to supply but without INH pin we cannot enable the PMIC  which Powers the system ( simple words there is no power )

Comment: Please draw a schematic.

Comment: _"Is there a passive components which can take 4 inputs and one output."_ Four resistors? _"Is there a diode with 4 input and single output?"_ Four diodes in OR configuration?

Comment: The way you do this depends on which PMIC you're using and whether the INH signals are active high or low.

Comment: @winny Thanks for the reply please find the rough block diagram above

Comment: Thanks. Do the "INH" share ground? What voltage level are we talking about? Would 4 Schottky diodes suffice?

Comment: Don't you need to power the CAN transcievers at all times?  If not, how do they generate the INH signal?  If the CAN transcievers have power, an OR gate can use that power.